# Invalid Bundle while submitting swift app + framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, app-store-connect, swift2

My app is in swift and depends on a private framework (dynamic not static) in swift+obj-C (includes Parse libs) which manages call to Parse.com APIs.

I followed this [tuto](http://insert.io/framework-ios8-xcode6/) to build my app in a workspace.

Code is running fine on my iPhone.

Archiving is fine (if I uncheck 'Include app symbols' or it fails like [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14729)) but I received a mail from iTunes Connect with this message :

> Invalid Bundle - This app includes files that were built with bitcode enabled but without doing an Archive or Install build, possibly from a library or framework that was imported but not built as part of the project. Full bitcode content is only generated in an Archive or Install build.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

It's been three times I checked and rechecked my build settings and I can't find what I missed.

My conf :

- iOS9
- Swift2
- ObjC
- XCode Version 7.0 (7A220)
- Parse

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem as you but unfortunately I cannot disable bitcode because of my watchkit extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable Bitcode support

`Project > Build Settings > All > Build Options > Enable Bitcode = NO`

Maybe your library was compiled without Bitcode, but the setting above is enabled in your project by default in Xcode7

Comment: OK I'll try it and let you know

Comment: That was it ! Well done ! Even if I won't have optimization and detailed crash reports from Apple...

Comment: This is not workable if bit code is required like apple watch extensions.

Comment: @Adeel: where you able to find a workaround for apple watch extensions?

Comment: @danny Bravo not yet dear. i have not tried after that.